# There is not enough space...!?

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I read at Wikipedia about [space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(mathematics)):

[image]

I understand that

- a metric space is a set for which elements a metric is definied.
- the Euclidean space [uses the Euclidean metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space#Metric_structure)
- a [Hilberts space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) generalizes the Euclidean space to spaces of infinite dimensionality. I guess, this means it also uses the Euclidean distance.
- a Banach space does [not necessarily use the Euclidean metric as a metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space#Examples_2).

Q1: What do you call a space, that is like the Euclidean space in every regard, except it uses a different metric - let's say the Manhatten metric? I guess that would make this space a [multivariate real coordinate space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_coordinate_space#Euclidean_space) ($R^n$) that uses a different metric?

Q2: Where did the metric definition "get lost"? In other words, what do you call a space that is like a Hilbert space in every regard, except it uses a different metric - let's say the Manhatten metric?

Shouldn't the graphic than look more like this:

[image]

Comment: If you have a vector space with a norm (or dot product, which induces a norm), that gives rise to a unique metric. If you, in addition, impose a second metric on that space, then I don't think there is a single conventional name for what you have. That being said, you can _always_ fit in more things in a diagram like that. It's not a question of "is there something there?" but rather "is there something there which is important enough and distinct enough to deserve to take up space in this diagram?"

Comment: @Arthur: I did not plan to have a second metric. The Euclidean space has only one metric as well. So, are you saying that there is no name for a space that is complete and has a dot product that results in the Manhatten metric? (Q2)

Comment: I sincerely doubt that there _is_ a dot product that results in the Manhattan metric.

Answer (score 5):

First let me address your question "Shouldn't the graphic look like this?".

If you follow the link you provided back to that Wikipedia page, and if you read the caption below that diagram, and if you also check each arrow to verify, you will see that the diagram has the following feature: each arrow $A \to B$ can be interpreted as "Every type $A$ object is an example of a type $B$ object". Thus, for example, finite dimensional Euclidean space is an example of a Hilbert space, which is an example of a Banach space, which is an example of a Normed vector space, and so on.

Your diagram does not have that feature. Suppose you take something in your Q2 box, which (I think) means any metric on $\mathbb R^n$. The result might not be an inner product space, nor even a Banach space. I could, for example, pick a diffeomorphism $f : \mathbb R^2 \to B^2$, where $B^2$ denotes the open ball, and then I could pull the $B^2$ metric back to $\mathbb R^2$ using the function $f$. The resulting metric on $\mathbb R^2$ would have finite diameter. But, every Banach space, and every inner product space, has infinite diameter.

Regarding your Q1, $\mathbb R^2$ equipped with the Manhattan metric **is** an example of a Banach space. In fact, any norm on any finite dimensional vector space (such as $\mathbb R^n$) defines a metric that is automatically complete, and therefore it **is** an example of a Banach space. (Similarly, any finite dimensional vector space, equipped with a metric realized by a dot product, is necessarily complete, and therefore is a Hilbert space.)

Regarding your Q2, you have given two versions of it, one version in your diagram, and a different version in the comments. Let me address both. Q2 in your diagram is handled by my earlier example using a diffeomorphism between $\mathbb R^n$ and an open ball in Euclidean $n$ space. Q2 in your comment is handled by an important fact: the Manhattan metric **is not realized** by any dot product, so it **is** a Banach space, and it **is not** a Hilbert space.

Comment: "Your diagram does not have that feature." I intended it to have that feature ;-).

Comment: I do not mean "any metric on Euclidean space" with Q2. Euclidean space already forces me to use the Euclidean metric - at least that is what Wikipedia seemed to suggest. As far as I understand that is the point of the Euclidean space: That the Euclidean metric is used as the metric.

Comment: What do you mean by "The resulting metric on $\mathbb R^2$ would have finite diameter. You did not define a metric... Do you mean that apply $f$ to $x,y\in\mathbb R^2$, then calculate a distance for the points $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ in the ball and then use that distance as the metric distance between $x$ and $y$? Do you then, further, mean that any two points $x,y$ can never be farther apart than the radius of the ball, making it finite?

Comment: Regarding Q1: Is there a name for a space that has any metric (like Manhatten, not necessarily Euclidean metric), is allowed to not have a dot product, and (now, unlike Banach space) must have finite dimensionality?

Comment: Banach space is NOT required to be of infinite dimension.

Comment: Regarding your question "What do you mean...", yes, that is the exact meaning of "pull the $B^2$ metric back to $\mathbb R^2$ using the function $f$".

Comment: Regarding your question "I do not mean...", my apologies. Topologists (like myself) often use "Euclidean space" to mean $\mathbb R^n$ with only its topological structure, ignoring its metric structure. But I see by the context of your question that you did indeed mean $\mathbb R^n$ with the ordinary Euclidean metric. I rewrote the answer with "$\mathbb R^n$" replacing "Euclidean space" in the appropriate places.

Comment: Which space is not required to have infinite diameter?

Comment: "Banach space is NOT required to be of infinite dimension" I know. It can be finite or infinite. For Q1 I want the name for a $\mathbb R^n$ (real coordinate) complete normed vector space with any metric, that *must* be finite, not *can* be finite.

Comment: I guess, for Q2 I want the name for a $\mathbb R^n$ (real coordinate) complete normed vector space with an metric, that *can* be finite vor infinite* and oft finite diameter.

Comment: Q1 should also be allowed to habe finite diameter.

Comment: I think I'll just leave my answer as it is, with a few final comments to summarize some of the points I have repeated earlier. Namely, every norm on $\mathbb R^n$ defines a normed vector space which (1) is of *finite* dimension, namely dimension $n$; (2) is of *infinite* diameter; and (3) is a Banach space.